# How to use json data that I receive from MongoDB in flutter?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, flutter, parsing

I want to use the json data that I receive from mongodb on to my flutter client.

The format of my mongodb document is:

```
{
    "_id":"2020-10-10 18:35:19.465085",
    "classhours":"56",    
    "sleephours":"56",
    "studyhours":"56",
    "activity":"9.0"
}
```

I am able to fetch data like this:

```
 db = await mongo.Db.create(
        "mongodb+srv://id:pass@cluster0.qkmvt.mongodb.net/students?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
    await db.open();

    print('DB Connected');
    coll = db.collection(widget.uid);
    print(coll);
    var response = await coll.find();
    print(response);
```

I am able to print all the documents in the console using this. How to use the response in the client ui like for text.Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FutureBuilder widget to set Text widget with value that you receive from asynchronous calls.

For more info refer: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the JSON response to a Map. Here's an example

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  var db="{\"_id\":\"2020-10-10 18:35:19.465085\",\r\n\"classhours\":\"56\",    \r\n \"sleephours\":\"56\",\r\n\"studyhours\":\"56\",\r\n\"activity\":\"9.0\"\r\n}";
  Map<String, dynamic> db_map=jsonDecode(db);
  print(db_map['_id']);
}
```

Or you can make a Plain Old Dart Object of the response using [Quicktype](https://quicktype.io/). Here is what you would get

```dart
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final dbModel = dbModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

DbModel dbModelFromJson(String str) => DbModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dbModelToJson(DbModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DbModel {
    DbModel({
        this.id,
        this.classhours,
        this.sleephours,
        this.studyhours,
        this.activity,
    });

    DateTime id;
    String classhours;
    String sleephours;
    String studyhours;
    String activity;

    factory DbModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DbModel(
        id: DateTime.parse(json["_id"]),
        classhours: json["classhours"],
        sleephours: json["sleephours"],
        studyhours: json["studyhours"],
        activity: json["activity"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id.toIso8601String(),
        "classhours": classhours,
        "sleephours": sleephours,
        "studyhours": studyhours,
        "activity": activity,
    };
}
```

After you receive your response, just use

```dart
DbModel model=DbModel.fromJson(json.decode(db));
print(model._id); // Access whatever variables you want
```

EDIT 1: In my example, I have hardcoded the response as a String variable db. This is equivalent to the response variable as mentioned in the question